# Backbone JS save functionality

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

I have written a rails back end to my project and when you save or create a new record,among the status 200 and a json representation of the post that was saved.

When I do the following in bacbone:

```
   modelObject = new App.Models.Post();
   modelObject.set({title: 'asdasdas', content: 'asdadasdasdasdasd'});

   if (modelObject.isValid()){
     modelObject.save().then( ... )
   }
```

How do I get the post object that is returned? (assuming the post is successful).

On the rails side, when I do `@post.save` I also do render `json: @post, status: 200` on a successful save in the create action so there is a json object coming back, I just dot know how to access it on the backbone side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) describe few ways how can you get response from server after calling `save()` function.
For example:

You need to specify `error` and `success` callbacks:

```
var model = new App.Models.Post();
model.set({title: 'some title', content: 'some content'});
var options = {
    success: function(model, response){
        console.log('success handler');
        model.set({id: response.id});
    },
    error: function(model, xhr){
        console.log('error handler');
    }
};
```

Specify `wait` option to wait response from server before set model attributes:

```
options.wait = true;
```

Need to call `save` function with specified options:

```
if (model.isValid()) {
    model.save({}, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modelObject.save() call will return a promise object. You should chain a .done() call to that and pass it in a function, like this:

```
modelObject.save().done(function(e) {
  // handle your response here
});
```

You could also handle a failure the same way using the .fail() function. Chain them together like this:

```
modelObject.save().done(function(e) {
  // handle your response here
}).fail(function(e) {
  // handle failure here
});
```

Here's another way to write the same code:

```
var promise = modelObject.save();
promise.done(function(e) {
  // handle your response here
});
promise.fail(function(e) {
  // handle failure here
});
```

There is also a .always() that you could chain to always be called:

```
var promise = modelObject.save();
promise.done(function(e) {
  // handle your response here
});
promise.fail(function(e) {
  // handle failure here
});
promise.always(function(e) {
  // always call this on success or failure
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question of how do i get the post json that comes back through the successful save. It helps me write this better but not help me understand the "and this is how you get the post json that comes back .... " part.